# WSO2 Identity Server: Cannot assign user role with SCIM

Tags: wso2, roles, identity

I am using **WSO2 IS 4.1.0**.When trying to assign a role by using **SCIM** i got following message in server log.

```
[2013-05-05 22:28:58,481]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.identity.scim.provider.impl.SCIMUserManager} -  User: dinuka is created through SCIM.
```

It's not assigning roles to he user but role "everyone" assigned always.

Following is my **JSON** posted to the **WSO2** IS

```
{"schemas":[],"userName":"chaminda","password":"pissek","name":{"familyName":"Gunawardena","givenName":"chaminda"},"emails":[{"primary":"true","value":"lc2002lk@yahoo.com","type":"home"}],"addresses":{"streetAddress":"Test
Address1","formatted":"Test
Address2","locality":"Galle","region":"Shouthern","country":"Sri
Lanka","postalCode":"8000"},"phoneNumbers":[{"primary":"true","value":"0094
714 209 800","type":"work"}],"displayName":"Test
Display","title":"Tech. Lead","roles":["admin"]}
```

User is creating successfully but never assigned to the given role.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the query, When adding a user you may pass a curl command  as

```
curl -v -k --user admin:admin --data "{"schemas":[],"userName":"userone","password":"userone"}" --header "Content-Type:application/json" https://{hostname}:{port}/wso2/scim/Users
```

where a user by the name "userone" is created,the system will generate a response with an ID such as ex: "0f9b34f6-7c44-4d64-a949-1ee4266097a9" generated, when adding a role we need to pass that generated ID for the created user along with the created users display name as shown below.

According to the below curl command, a role by the name "myrole01" should be created which includes a the user with a name "userone".

```
curl -v -k --user admin:admin --data "{"displayName": "myrole01","members": [{"value":"0f9b34f6-7c44-4d64-a949-1ee4266097a9","display": "userone"}]}" --header "Content-Type:application/json" https://{hostname}:{port}/wso2/scim/Groups
```

Comment: Yes, then you have to send all previous users+new user